# Iterate all 'select' elements and get all their values in Selenium

Tags: c#, javascript, select, xpath, selenium

I have the following code in C# using selenium:

```
private void SelectElementFromList(string label)
    {
        var xpathcount = selenium.GetXpathCount("//select");
        for (int i = 1; i <= xpathcount; ++i)
        {
            string[] options;
            try
            {
                options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("//select["+i+"]");
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }
            foreach (string option in options)
            {
                if (option == label)
                {
                    selenium.Select("//select[" + i + "]", "label=" + label);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the line:

```
options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("//select["+i+"]");
```

When i == 1 this works, but when i > 1 the method return null ("ERROR: Element //select[2] not found"). It works only when i == 1.

I have also tried this code in JS:

```
var element = document.evaluate("//select[1]/option[1]/@value", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
alert(element.iterateNext());
var element = document.evaluate("//select[2]/option[1]/@value", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
alert(element.iterateNext());
```

Which print on the screen "[object Attr]" and then "null".

What am I doing wrong?
My goal is to iterate all "select" elements on the page and find the one with the specified label and select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution.
I've just replaced these lines

```
options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("//select["+i+"]");
selenium.Select("//select["+i+"]", "label="+label);
```

with these

```
options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("//descendant::select[" + i + "]");
selenium.Select("//descendant::select[" + i + "]", "label=" + label);
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is the second most FAQ in XPath (the first being unprefixed names and default namespace**.

In your code:

```
options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("//select["+i+"]");
```

An expression of the type is evaluated:

```
//select[position() =$someIndex]
```

which is a synonym for:

```
//select[$someIndex]
```

when it is known that `$someIndex` has an integer value.

However, by definition of the `//` XPath pseudo-operator,

```
//select[$k]
```

when `$k` is integer, means:

"*Select all `select` elements in the document that are the `$k`-th `select` child of their parent*."

> When `i == 1` this works, but when `i > 1` the method return `null` ("ERROR:
>   Element //select[2] not found"). It works only when i == 1.

This simply means that in the XML document there is no element that has more than one `select` child.

**This is a rule to remember**: The `[]` XPath operator has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator.

**The solution**: As always when we need to override the default precedence of operators, we must use brackets.

**Change**:

```
options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("//select["+i+"]");
```

**to**:

```
options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("(//select)["+i+"]");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I've tried your code in both Javascript and selenium. In Javascritp after adding the brackets this works fine, but in selenium I am still getting an exception "ERROR: Element (//select)[2] not found".

Comment: @Darxis: This means that Selenium isn't a compliant XPath 1.0 implementation. I would strongly recommend *not* to use any incompliant XPath engine. I don't know Selenium, but if you can first select all `select` elements (`//select`) in an array of XmlNode -like objects. then you can just process each item of this array.

Comment: Selenium **is** XPath 1.0 compliant, and selectors like `(//select)[2]` work just fine.  The problem must be something else.  But since the page's HTML hasn't been given to us, there's no way to know what's wrong for sure.

Comment: @RossPatterson: Thank you. I guess the OP hasn't shared with us some important information.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution `options = selenium.GetSelectOptions("(//select)["+i+"]");` doesn't worked for me but i tried to use css selectors.

I want to get username and password text box. I tried with `css=input` this gave me Username text box and when used `css=input+input` this gave me Password textbox.

along with this selectors you can use many things in combination.

[here](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/) is the link from where i read.

I think this will help u to achieve your target.

Regards.